# Storing command structs with "generic" data

Tags: rust, traits

I have the following trait:

```rs
pub trait Command {
    /// The expected arguments.
    type Payload;

    /// Returns the command ID.
    fn id(&self) -> &'static str {
        "0"
    }

    /// Returns the expected number of arguments.
    fn args_count(&self) -> usize {
        1
    }

    /// Parses the arguments.
    fn parse(&self, args: Vec<&str>) -> Result<Self::Payload, CommandError>;

    /// The function to run.
    fn run(&self, args: Self::Payload) -> Result<Option<Vec<String>>, CommandError>;
}
```

and it can be used like this

```rs
/// Sets the clipboard's content.
pub struct SetClipboard;
impl Command for SetClipboard {
    type Payload = String;

    fn id(&self) -> &'static str {
        "2"
    }

    fn args_count(&self) -> usize {
        1
    }

    fn parse(&self, args: Vec<&str>) -> Result<Self::Payload, CommandError> {
        Ok(args.join(""))
    }

    fn run(&self, payload: Self::Payload) -> Result<Option<Vec<String>>, CommandError> {
        // Set clipboard
        if let Err(e) = set_clipboard(formats::Unicode, payload) {
            return Err(CommandError::SystemError(e.raw_code()))
        };

        // Return
        Ok(None)
    }
}
```

However, I need to reference these "commands" of course. So I'll store them in an array but what do I set the `Payload` type as?

```rs
pub type Commands = Vec<Box<dyn Command<Payload = dyn std::any::Any>>>;
...
let commands: Commands = vec![
    Box::new(MouseMoveRel),
    Box::new(MouseMoveAbs),
    Box::new(SetClipboard)
];
```

(this doesn't work due to a type-mismatch).

For each command, I would check if it something matches the same command id to figure out which one to use. This is done within a WebSocket message from a client (as the server).

```rs
// Split the text
// Format: `COMMAND ID|JOB ID|ARGUMENTS
let split: Vec<&str> = text.split("|").collect();

// Check the length of the arguments
if split.len() < 2 {
    return ctx.text(CommandError::BadlyFormattedCommand)
}

// Find which command
let command_id = split[0];
let Some(command) = self.commands.iter().find(|x| x.id() == command_id) else {
    return ctx.text(CommandError::CouldNotFindCommand)
};

// Check the length of the arguments
if split.len() - 2 < command.args_count() {
    return ctx.text(CommandError::NotEnoughArguments)
}

// Parse the arguments
let parsed = match command.parse(split[2..].to_vec()) {
    Ok(x) => x,
    Err(e) => return ctx.text(e)
};

// Run the command
match command.run(parsed) {
    Ok(x) => match x {
        Some(data) => ctx.text(CommandResponse {
            id: split[1].to_owned(),
            data
        }),
        None => ()
    },
    Err(e) => ctx.text(e)
}
```

Is there a better way of doing this instead?

Note: Payload can be any type, either a String or a tuple of arbitrary length e.g. (i32, i32) or (String, i32, i32) etc.

Comment: It's not possible to accomplish the pattern you want via a trait with associated type as you have here. I would recommend merging `parse` and `run` so you don't need the associated type.

Comment: But if all of your commands are known at compile time, I would recommend using an enum instead.

Comment: Enums are a great idea, I'm not sure how I would implement them though and that's why I went with this route instead. If you could point me in the right direction, that would be great.

Comment: @Stefanuk12 each command is an enum variant. Implement `run` on the enum type with a `match` that does the right thing based on variant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider approaching this from the type level. A `Command` can be parsed from some string input and knows how to execute some action and return its result.

```rust
use std::str::FromStr;

pub enum CommandError {
    BadlyFormattedCommand,
    CouldNotFindCommand,
    NotEnoughArguments,
}

pub enum Commands {
    SetClipboard(String),
    MouseMoveRel(i32, i32),
    MouseMoveAbs(i32, i32),
}

impl FromStr for Commands {
    type Err = CommandError;

    fn from_str(s: &str) -> Result<Self, Self::Err> {
        match s.split("|").collect::<Vec<&str>>().as_slice() {
            ["1", value] => Ok(Commands::SetClipboard(value.to_string())),
            ["1", ..] => Err(CommandError::NotEnoughArguments),
            ["2", x, y] => {
                let x: i32 = x.parse().map_err(|_| CommandError::BadlyFormattedCommand)?;
                let y: i32 = y.parse().map_err(|_| CommandError::BadlyFormattedCommand)?;
                Ok(Commands::MouseMoveRel(x, y))
            }
            ["2", ..] => Err(CommandError::NotEnoughArguments),
            ["3", x, y] => {
                let x: i32 = x.parse().map_err(|_| CommandError::BadlyFormattedCommand)?;
                let y: i32 = y.parse().map_err(|_| CommandError::BadlyFormattedCommand)?;
                Ok(Commands::MouseMoveAbs(x, y))
            }
            ["3", ..] => Err(CommandError::NotEnoughArguments),
            _ => Err(CommandError::CouldNotFindCommand),
        }
    }
}

pub struct CommandResponse; // I won't define this, but maybe this is actually an enum?

impl Commands {
    pub fn execute(&self) -> Result<Option<CommandResponse>, CommandError> {
        match self {
            Self::SetClipboard(s) => {
                // do that thing
                Ok(None)
            }
            Self::MouseMoveRel(x, y) => {
                // do that thing
                Ok(Some(CommandResponse)) // Maybe this is the new location?
            }
            Self::MouseMoveAbs(x, y) => {
                // do THAT thing
                Ok(Some(CommandResponse))
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Then using the code is:

```rust
def run_command(s: &str) -> Result<Option<CommandResult>, ApplicationError> {
    // Parse the command
    command: Command = s.parse().map_err(|_| ApplicationError)?;

    // and return the result of its execution
    command.execute().map_err(|_| ApplicationError)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would do something like this, using enums and merging `parse` and `run`. This uses the try operator `?` to propagate errors.

```rust
struct Unicode;
struct SetClipboardError;

fn set_clipboard(format: Unicode, s: &str) -> Result<(), SetClipboardError> {
    todo!()
}

struct CommandError;

// so `?` can convert automagically
impl From<SetClipboardError> for CommandError {
    fn from(other: SetClipboardError) -> CommandError {
        todo!()
    }
}

enum Command {
    MouseMoveAbs,
    SetClipboard,
}

impl Command {
    fn from_id(id: &str) -> Result<Self, CommandError> {
        match id {
            "1" => Ok(Self::MouseMoveAbs),
            "2" => Ok(Self::SetClipboard),

            _ => Err(CommandError), // CouldNotFindCommand
        }
    }
    fn parse_and_run(&self, args: &[&str]) -> Result<Option<Vec<String>>, CommandError> {
        match self {
            Self::MouseMoveAbs => {
                todo!()
            }
            Self::SetClipboard => {
                if args.len() < 1 {
                    return Err(CommandError); // NotEnoughArguments
                }

                // Set clipboard
                set_clipboard(Unicode, args[0])?;

                // Return
                Ok(None)
            }
        }
    }
}

struct CommandResponse {
    id: String,
    data: Vec<String>,
}

fn run_command(text: &str) -> Result<Option<CommandResponse>, CommandError> {
    // Split the text
    // Format: `COMMAND ID|JOB ID|ARGUMENTS
    let split: Vec<&str> = text.split("|").collect();

    // Check the length of the arguments
    if split.len() < 2 {
        return Err(CommandError); // BadlyFormattedCommand
    }

    // Find which command
    let command = Command::from_id(split[0])?;

    // Parse the arguments and run the command
    if let Some(data) = command.parse_and_run(&split[2..])? {
        Ok(Some(CommandResponse {
            id: split[1].to_string(),
            data,
        }))
    } else {
        Ok(None)
    }
}
```

[playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=a76bd9b2d7d2df4f5065d6daaa1c8fe3)

Comment: `Command::from_id` should maybe be `TryFrom::<&str> for Command`

Comment: (Honestly, you might want to consider just `impl FromStr for Command` and teaching Command to own its own arguments!)

Answer (score 0):

Guys from the comments to your question are right. It would be hard to accomplish this task with the associated type.

You could use the enum for `Payload`. For example:

```
pub enum Payload {
    U32(u32),
    Tuple((String, u32, u32)),
    I32(i32),
    String(String),
}
```

You know all of your possible payloads, otherwise, you couldn't parse the command.
Then command implementation will look like this:

```
pub struct MouseMoveRel;

impl Command for MouseMoveRel {
    fn parse(&self, args: Vec<&str>) -> Result<Payload, CommandError> {
        Ok(Payload::String("".to_owned()))
    }

    fn run(&self, args: Payload) -> Result<Option<Vec<String>>, CommandError> {
        let Payload::String(data) = args else {
            return Err(CommandError);
        };
        // use data
        Ok(None)
    }
}
```

Also, you could improve it with `From` trait.

```
impl From<String> for Payload {
    fn from(value: String) -> Self {
        Self::String(value)
    }
}

// result of using the From trait
//fn parse(&self, args: Vec<&str>) -> Result<Payload, CommandError> {
//    Ok("".to_owned().into())
//}
```